# Vaadin how to add Google heat map

Tags: google-maps, vaadin, heatmap

I have a Vaadin application where I would like to integrate Google heatmaps. I am using *com.vaadin.tapio.googlemaps* dependency for displaying a map and it works fine. However, I am not sure how to add a heatmap layer on top of the Google map and I couldn't find any relevant resource.

Relevant part of my trial code looks like this:

```
    VerticalLayout rootLayout = new VerticalLayout();
    rootLayout.setSizeFull();

    // Google Map
    GoogleMap googleMap = new GoogleMap("api_key", null, null);
    googleMap.setZoom(10);
    googleMap.setSizeFull();
    googleMap.setMinZoom(4);
    googleMap.setMaxZoom(16);

    Panel mapsPanel = new Panel();
    mapsPanel.setSizeFull();
    mapsPanel.setContent(googleMap);
    rootLayout.addComponent(mapsPanel);

    double centerLon = 8.5417;
    double centerLat = 47.3769;
    googleMap.setCenter(new LatLon(centerLat, centerLon));
    GoogleMapMarker centerMarker = new GoogleMapMarker("Zurich", new LatLon(centerLat, centerLon),true, null);
    googleMap.addMarker(centerMarker);


    HeatMapLayer heatMapLayer = HeatMapLayer.newInstance(HeatMapLayerOptions.newInstance());
    // Add data to heatmap
    ...
    // How can I add this HeatMapLayer to the existing map?
    // Or do I need a different approach?

    UI.getCurrent().setContent(rootLayout);
```

Answer (score 1):

`HeatMapLayer` is a GWT (client-side) object, you can't use it directly with `GoogleMap` which is a server-side component. You can check [this fork](https://github.com/cuba-platform/vaadin-googlemaps) of *com.vaadin.tapio.googlemaps*, it adds support for `HeatMapLayer` with `GoogleMapHeatMapLayer` class.

Comment: I tried out the fork; however, their heatmap doesn't do anything for me. I tried both their demo and also integrated `GoogleMapHeatMapLayer` into my app, but neither worked. Nevertheless, thanks for the info.